Is any blowup a composition of finitely many blow-ups with smooth centers?
This question may be a well-known fact. However, I cannot find it in any reference. We always assume that the center of a blowup is a closed subvariety in this context.
Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a blow-up of a compact complex analytic space, with the center $Z$ (not necessarily smooth).
Question: Can we construct a series of blowups $X=X_0 \rightarrow X_1 \rightarrow X_2 \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow X_k \rightarrow X_{k+1}=Y$  such that each $f_i: X_i \rightarrow X_{i+1}$ has a smooth center?
Clues: Considering Hironaka's resolution theory, the answer seems to be "Yes." For smoothness, we may analyze the center $Z . Z$ is the union of the regular part of its reduction and the singular part of its reduction. However, the regular part of its reduction is not closed.

I suggest you to look into "Lectures on resolution of singularities" by János Kollár,

@Sasha Thank you. I have re-edited the post to assume the complex spaces are compact. Can you provide an answer in this setting? Any remarks, comments, or clues would be appreciated.
